# Is it possible to pass a built in function as an argument to a trigger?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-trigger

I ask this question in light of the following trigger producing this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 5: ...cessBlogPostApproval"('Blog Post Approval', concat('Your blo...
^
```

The trigger in question:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "processBlogPostApproval_AFTER_INSERT"
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public."ApprovedBlogPosts"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public."processBlogPostApproval"('Blog Post Approval', concat('Your blog post, "', SELECT "Title" FROM public."BlogPosts" WHERE "PostID" == NEW."PostID", '"has been approved.'));
```

The problem seems to be arising due to the fact that I passed a concatenation function as my second argument, or rather, that I did not pass it correctly. Would appreciate your assistance in identifying which of the two is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it turns out the easiest/cleanest way to do something is --- well not to do it. This seems to be the case here. The issue you are having deal with passing a message into a trigger function, that getting it properly formatted. Well since a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpgsql-trigger.html) must defined without parameters.

> A trigger procedure is created with the CREATE FUNCTION command,
>   declaring it as a function with no arguments and a return type of
>   trigger.

Don't do it. Build the message in the trigger function. It actually makes the code there easier (IMO). You didn't provide much detail so just a minimal example:

```
-- setup
create table approved_blog_posts( id integer ) ;
create table blog_posts(id integer, title text) ;

insert into blog_posts( id, title) 
values (1 ,'Blog Rant') 
     , (2 ,'Still Rant again')
     , (3 ,'Rambling about nut''en!');

-- trigger function 
create or replace function blog_post_approved()
  returns  trigger
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    l_title text; 
begin 
     select title
       into l_title
       from blog_posts
      where id = new.id;

    raise notice 'Your blog post "%" has been approved.',l_title;
    return new;
end; 
$$;  

-- attach trigger to table    
create trigger approved_blog_posts_air
    after insert
    on approved_blog_posts
    for each row
    execute procedure blog_post_approved();

 -- demo/test
 insert into approved_blog_posts(id) values (1),(3);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your (invaluable) feedback, and I will likely select this as the best answer as it appears to be the only viable answer in light of the [evidence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259612/201041) I gathered since posting this question. The reason I designed my trigger function with parameters was really as an attempt to abstract the function for re-usability purposes. It would have been great if there were a way to implement that instead of creating trigger functions for each of my tables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually comes from the usage of ", in the concatenation mechanism as well as on the objects naming.

I think you can avoid altogether the usage of " there as so:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.processBlogPostApproval('Blog Post Approval', concat('Your blog post, "', (SELECT Title FROM public.BlogPosts WHERE PostID == NEW.PostID), '" has been approved.'));
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but it doesn't seem to be the main problem here. For one, the DBMS tool I'm using (pgAdmin 4) inserts the quotation marks around the trigger  function name automatically, and prohibits me from manually tweaking the final SQL code, save for specifying the arguments in a text box. Secondly, when I put "normal" arguments (for example: 'Blog Post Approval', 'You have a new notification', 'blah blah blah'), the new trigger is committed to the database with no problems at all, despite `processBlogPostApproval` being enclosed in quotation marks.